# How can I connect to AS/400 through TN5250?

Tags: networking, ip, ibm-midrange

How will I find out my iseries server name? I checked through "nslookup" it gives one ip address & I tried to connect TN5250 session to cconnect but could not connect.
from dos command line

```
c:\nslookup
default server : unknown
ip address : 192.168.50.119
```

Then I tried ping with this IP address - it's giving reply from the above IP address

Then I have given this id in TN5250 session, but says can not create a connection to the AS/400.

Answer (score 2):

The iSeries server is just like any other server as regards its IP address. Do you know its name in DNS? If so, then that is all you should have to input to the TN5250 application.

Mocha Soft is correct in referring you to your local administrator because they have no way of knowing anything about your internal network.

If you absolutely need to know the IP address of your iSeries server then open a command line window (cmd.exe) and ping your iSeries server by name. The ping command will resolve the name to an address and print it out. Yes, you can also use nslookup but ping will also tell you if the server is reachable.

The IP address of your laptop is irrelevant.